# Выскакивает TimeoutException com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler.log

Tags: java, linux, rabbitmq, camunda

второй день не получается победить ошибку. сам таймаут по умолчанию 5 сек

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
29-Oct-2019 20:05:21.408 WARNING [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] 
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler.log An unexpected 
connection driver error occured (Exception message: Socket closed)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:315)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:64)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1095)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1012)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1170)
at ru.test.service.EventSender.sendEventToRabbit(EventSender.java:35)
at ru.test.service.BpmTaskListener.notify(BpmTaskListener.java:132)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.task.delegate.TaskListenerInvocation.invoke(TaskListenerInvocation.java:44)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:57)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocationInContext(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:90)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:62)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.fireEvent(TaskEntity.java:961)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:303)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.completeTask(CompleteTaskCmd.java:64)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:58)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:33)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:27)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:106)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:69)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:176)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.sub.task.impl.TaskResourceImpl.complete(TaskResourceImpl.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:140)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:109)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:135)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:103)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:377)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:200)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.filter.EmptyBodyFilter.doFilter(EmptyBodyFilter.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

Кто понимает вообще, в чем дело? Подскажите, куда капать.

В логах рэббита ошибка в этот момент есть

```
[warning] <0.24281.300> closing AMQP connection <0.24281.300> 
(127.0.0.1:47278 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Метод отправки события в рэббит

```
public static void sendEventToRabbit(BpmEvent event) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
         Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
        String message = mapper.writeValueAsString(event);
        channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, QUEUE_NAME, null, 
    message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: тут ничего не понятно. покажите код

Comment: @michael_best не могу показать, так как не владелец кода(( Хотя бы понять почему вообще такое происходит. возможно все таки в коде беда? Я кучу таких примеров перерыл в гугле, ничего толком не понятно

Comment: тут видно, что есть ошибка типа TimeoutException, а дальше методы, где куда программа заходит. все

Comment: @michael_best мне дали метод, который отправляет события в рэббит. Плохо ли что создается всегда новое соединение? Connection connection = factory.newConnection()

Comment: смотря как часто это происходит и какие у вас мощности. Если раз в день - то нормально, если раз в пол секунды - то не очень

Comment: а вообще создание объектов через new не самая хорошая стратегия. как вы потом его тестировать будете?

Comment: @michael_best Довольно часто вызывается, в секунду может до 500 вызовов. Мы сейчас установили параметр handshake timeout что ли, это вот как раз внутри метода. Получше стало, но все равно ошибка есть. Но все делаем по доке официальной. Если вы знаете, не могли бы подсказать, что лучше сделать?